# Separating interfaces and making them more generic

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I have an interface to define my records\models

```
public interface IStockItem
{
    string Code { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
    decimal FreeStock { get; set; }
}
```

Is it best to put the actions into another interface?

```
public interface IStockExport
{
    IEnumerable<IStockItem> GetAll();
    IEnumerable<IStockItem> GetStockByCode(string code);
    decimal GetFreeStock(string code);
}

public interface IStockImport
{
    void CreateItem<IStockItem>;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this and make it more generic? so i can share the actions interfaces with other records\models?

The other records\models are SalesOrder, Customer, Address.

The overall idea is an Import\Export program, that will create\export sales orders in a number of different accounts packages via an API.

Comment: You can make the interface generic, but this may or may not be desirable. What other types do you want to support? Do they logically need the same contract but only differ on type?

Comment: You better ask this question her http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common pattern, called the `Repository Pattern`.

If you want to go down this route, you should create a base interface, `Repository<T>`, for example:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    void Insert(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    IEnumerable<T> SearchFor(Func<T, bool> predicate);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    T GetById(int id);
}
```

You would make your `IStockItem` implement an `IEntity` interface so that it can provide an ID for `GetById()`, for example:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int ID { get; }
}
```

Then you would implement the repository for a data type such as `StockItem` by declaring the implementing class. It might start a bit like this:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity
{
    protected Table<T> DataTable;

    public Repository(DataContext dataContext)
    {
        DataTable = dataContext.GetTable<T>();
    }

    ...
```

Your code that wanted to get at a repository for a stock item might look like this:

```
using (var dataContext = new StockItemDataContext())
{
    var StockItemRepository = new Repository<IStockItem>(dataContext);
    ...
```

This may be overkill for what you want, but it is the general approach.

[For full details see this excellent blog post](http://www.remondo.net/repository-pattern-example-csharp/).

[Also see this example.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/821798/Repository-Pattern)

Here's how you might start implementing this pattern for your case:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    void Insert(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    IEnumerable<T> SearchFor(Func<T, bool> predicate);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    T GetByCode(string code);
}

public interface IStockItem: IEntity
{
    string Description { get; set; }
    decimal FreeStock { get; set; }
}

public sealed class StockItem: IStockItem
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal FreeStock { get; set; }
}

public interface IEntity
{
    string Code { get; }
}

public sealed class MyLowLevelDataAccess
{
    public StockItem FindStockItem(string code)
    {
        return null; // Call your API here.
    }

    public void DeleteStockItem(string code)
    {
        // Call your API here.
    }

    public void InsertStockItem(StockItem item)
    {
        // Call your API here.
    }

    public IEnumerable<StockItem> FindAllItems()
    {
        return FindItemsMatching(x => true);
    }

    public IEnumerable<StockItem> FindItemsMatching(Func<StockItem, bool> predicate)
    {
        return null; // Call your API here and return all items matching the predicate.
    }
}

public sealed class StockRepository: IRepository<StockItem>
{
    private readonly MyLowLevelDataAccess _dataAccess;

    public StockRepository(MyLowLevelDataAccess dataAccess)
    {
        _dataAccess = dataAccess;
    }

    public void Insert(StockItem entity)
    {
        _dataAccess.InsertStockItem(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(StockItem entity)
    {
        _dataAccess.DeleteStockItem(entity.Code);
    }

    public IEnumerable<StockItem> SearchFor(Func<StockItem, bool> predicate)
    {
        return _dataAccess.FindItemsMatching(predicate);
    }

    public IEnumerable<StockItem> GetAll()
    {
        return _dataAccess.FindAllItems();
    }

    public StockItem GetByCode(string code)
    {
        return _dataAccess.FindStockItem(code);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how to create the implementing class and how to get the repository (I understand the base interface part). I'm not using Linq to SQL or Entity Framework. Most of the time to get stock items, i will have to query one of four accounts systems via an API.

Comment: @user2859298 In that case you would hand-implement the methods that get the actual data.

Comment: @downvoter: It is generally considered helpful to explain what you think is wrong with an answer, to educate not only the person who wrote it, but also those who read it.

Comment: Being a entity based solution I would suggest changing `IEnumerable<T> SearchFor(Func<T, bool> predicate);` to `IEnumerable<T> SearchFor(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);` so that if you are working with IQueryable objects underneath the repository the filters can happen server side instead of in RAM client side.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain It does use `Expression<>` in the blog that I linked, but I simplified it for this example because it seems that the OP is not using an Entity framework or Linq-to-SQL (see his first comment to my answer).

Answer (score 2):

you can use a generic interface as well:

```
public interface IRecordExport<T> where T : IRecordBase
{
  IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
  IEnumerable<T> GetOneByCode(string code);
  decimal GetFree(string code);
}

public interface IRecordImport<T> where T : IRecordBase
{
  void CreateItem<T>();
}
```

Comment: There is a missing `<T>` in `IStockImport` declaration.

Comment: This is not the same as his interface declaration tho' as ideally you'd need a `where T : IStockItem` in there too, in which case, why bother making it fully generic?

Comment: I don't like this interface at all, because it has the `Stock` in its name, which relates to the specific records class and is not generic at all. I'll rework it a bit

Answer (score 1):

You could, but it may not be necessary. Interfaces for method-based classes are best used where you want to have polymorphism related to implementation.

In your case, it seems that what you want is to be able to share common functionality (based on the `IStockExport` interface) but also provide a polymorphic creation mechanism (based on `IStockImport`).

I would suggest that you implement an abstract base class for `IStockExport` which can be inherited for all the various types of `IStockItem` (due to common interface) and then the derived classes should implement `IStockExport` as each `Create<IStockItem>()` implementation will be different but can be used in the same way due to common behaviour (always returns `IStockItem` object).